# Correctly store Client Secrets in database for discourse-openid-connect

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid, discourse

I have used a Discourse Docker image to get Discourse running, and used the following [openid-connect](https://github.com/discourse/discourse-openid-connect) plugin so that users can signup / login to our forum via our web app which is using IdentityServer4

I can get it working if I don't require client secrets, but when I set it to require client secrets, authorization fails.

[plugin settings][1]

I added the client secret in the plugin as you can see the settings in the image, and then added the secrets in plain-text to the relevant cell in the database.

I assume the fact it works without requiring secrets but then fails when I require it, is because Discourse plugin will be processing the secret in some way, like sha256 etc, and that is why its failing, as I have stored the password in plain-text and its not matching the processed secret given by Discourse.

Does anyone have any ideas what process I would need to put my secrets through to store it correctly in the database, so that authentication succeeds? or is my issue likely something else ?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Default type of secret is [shared secret](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/Storage/src/Models/Secret.cs#L51) on IdentityServer. To define a shared secret you can use [Sha256 extension method](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Extensions/HashExtensions.cs#L22). Run sth like the code bellow for ur secret and save the result in DB

```
"secret".Sha256()
```

Read more about secrets [here](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/secrets.html)

Comment: Thanks Nahidf for the reference, I tried that but still no joy, I will keep looking